# CSS background image on hover with logo

Tags: css, image, background, hover

Hiall,
I have a problem. I must add hover images on menu like in picture. I understand I must create for each item in the menu a special picture, but how should I add it to style.css? Please give me an answer

web for testing:

> tee.jecool.net

image:
[image]
menu-item-2

menu-item-14

menu-item-21

menu-item-26

menu-item-391

menu-item-23

menu-item-28

28.2.2014 - 23:08 =

Thanks for answers guys! Im not good in css. I teach only some basics. This web i make from Artisteer and some html changes + css changes.

I find on another web this code and i think this is what i want, but its not working:

```
 #menu-item-2 a:hover {
    background: url(http://www.tee.jecool.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Dotaz_css_hover_image.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Is this problem, because i have another hover in menu? (red tee cup effect)? I must this turn off in artisster template? And after this write this to style.css? How i code exactly position? And is this "#menu-item-2 a:hover..." correct?

3.3.2014 =

Hi, i little work on it and finally i make some progress :-). Here is my testing web for now = buh.jecool.net. And now on hover show my black button. But he changed menu and pull over text from menu away. How edit this? Code now look:

```
ul.art-hmenu>li>a:hover, 
.desktop ul.art-hmenu>li:hover>a {
   color: #D41217;
   text-decoration: none;
   height: 99px;
   width: 83px;
   background: url(http://www.tee.jecool.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Menu_hover_blog.png) no-repeat;
}
```

And i must create special picture button for all menu items? I mean menu-item-2, 14, 21 etc.? How looks this code? Pleas give answer. Thanks :-).

I want learn this so much! Pleas give me clou! Thanks. **You want my style.css or html somewhere upload?** Sorry for my bad EN.

Comment: Can you please explain your needs in a little more detail, and show us your HTML?  Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

If all of them are anchors you can simply write a rule as (in case you can modify the html):

```
#menu a {
    background-image: none;
}

#menu a:hover {
    background: url('/images/my_background_image.jpg') top left no-repeat;
}
```

Maybe you will need to change some padding / margin to create a nice effect.

If you cannot modify the html file... just write rules for all of them.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I put this to style.css and change url for picture but nothing changed...

Comment: Must i put this code to style.css or somewhere else? Where exactly? I put this to style.css but nothing changed. Can you, pleas, give me more specific information. Im sorry, but im not so good in this css. –  user3366349

Comment: Probably it wont change because the route to the image is not good. Where is you html file? where your css file? and where your images?

Comment: Hi, i little work on it and finally i make some progress :-). Here is my testing web for now = http://www.buh.jecool.net/. And now on hover show my black button. But he changed menu and pull over text from menu away. How edit this?  Code now look: `ul.art-hmenu>li>a:hover, 
.desktop ul.art-hmenu>li:hover>a {
   color: #D41217;
   text-decoration: none;
   height: 99px;
   width: 83px;
   background: url(http://www.tee.jecool.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Menu_hover_blog.png) no-repeat;`
}

Comment: And i must create special picture button for all menu items? I mean menu-item-2, 14, 21 etc.? How looks this code? Pleas give answer. Thanks :-). I want learn this so much! Pleas give me clou! Thanks. You want my style. css or html somewhere upload? Sorry for my bad EN.

Comment: Following you story... each menu item has a different logo so... yes, maybe you will need different css rules for each one related to each class or id of the elements.

Comment: Another problem you have here is that... each item has a different width, so you cannot force all of them to be 83px. In addition some tweak in the padding could be nice ;)

I recommend you to use a plain (and small) background and repeat it in the x axis / or simple put background-color: black. Then use border-radius to make rounded borders and the only thing you must change is the small image in the middle and centered.

Answer (score 0):

Some base to start with:

http://jsfiddle.net/f9ncq/

**HTML**

```
<div>
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="https://wiki.debian.org/htdocs/debwiki/img/openlogo-50.png" />
        aaaaa
    </li>
    <li><img src="https://wiki.debian.org/htdocs/debwiki/img/openlogo-50.png" />
        bbbb</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul li img {
    display: none;
}

ul li:hover img {
    display: inline;
}
```